# search good resources to implement memcached with doctrine 1.2 and zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, memcached, doctrine-1.2

I search a good resources with examples to use a doctrine memcached and zend framework.

i search in google but not found, i need resource that Combine all this things.

using `Doctrine_Cache_Memcache` in zend framework.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ZF and Doctrine integration see: [beberlei's zf-doctrine at GitHub](http://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine)

To enable cache, in your application `Bootstrap.php`:

```
public function _initDoctrineCache()
{
    $this->bootstrap('doctrine');

    $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();

    $cacheDriver = null;

    if (extension_loaded('memcache')) {
        $servers = array(
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 11211,
            'persistent' => true
        );

        $cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Memcache(array(
                    'servers' => $servers,
                    'compression' => false
                        )
        );
    } else if (function_exists('apc_add')) {
        $cacheDriver = new Doctrine_Cache_Apc();
    }

    if (null !== $cacheDriver) {
        //$manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_QUERY_CACHE, $cacheDriver);
        $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE, $cacheDriver);
        $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_RESULT_CACHE_LIFESPAN, 120); // in seconds
    }

    return $cacheDriver;
    }
```

Of course, you need to have `apc`, `memcache` and `memcached` installed first.

Comment: thanks , when i call to this function _initDoctrineCache ? only first time , every time i want to cache query , if you can show me the uses of this function in caching sql doctrine queries

Comment: @Haim This function is placed in Bootstrap, so it automatically runs. No need to call it manually.